# How to add multiple GIFs to Android GridView

Tags: android, gif, android-gridview

How to add multiple GIFs to Android GridView? Let's assume that we have a 4*4 grid (16 cells), with a different individual animated GIF image being shown in each cell in such a way that each image is animating on its own. Therefore creating a GIF of 16 different videos/animations, all playing at the same time in 16 separate cells.

Comment: yes it is possible . you may have list of Gif images so that you can send that list to your grid adapter  . for this you can use Glide / Picasso to load git images

Comment: @TalhaBilal how can yo explain it more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First Step

In you **GridAdapter** make a function

```
public void upadteList(List<yourGifList> list){
         this.gifList = list;
         notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
```

then in **OnBind** Method 
call
 `Glide.with(context).asGif().load(gifList).into(imageView);`

## Second

In your activity call **upadteList()** method
 `gridAdapter.updateList(imagesList);`

**Note :** i am assuming you are already have a recyclerView setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recyclerview or gridview. Then use Glide library in your adapter

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);
Glide.with(context).load(yourGif).into(imageViewTarget);
```

or

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Glide.with(context).asGif().load(yourGif).into(imageView);
```

Comment: can you explain it more brother.. @Beyazid